# Parse SWIFT(Financial) message string with REGEX in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I am working on a Powershell script to parse SWIFT messages (text based) into a database. I am using REGEX to find the appropriate strings in the file and extract them. I now run into the issue that one of the data fields can have CR/LF characters in the string - in the example below I would need to extract the second line as well.

```
:61:2111261126D12000,00NTRF11000004217657P//03MT211124101166
JANE DOE  1232
```

I tested this regex pattern `(:61:.*[\r\n].*)` in RegExr and it recognizes the `[\r\n]` characters as requirement to be valid, so my plan was to have two expressions - one with and one without CR/LF characters to identify both messages - either with line break or without - however the code below will return all matches no matter whether a line break in included or not - it seems that PS stops evaluation strings after CR/LF.

```
$transaction = $swift | select-string ‘:61:.*[\r\n].*’ -AllMatches  | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }
```

Can I use REGEX for this task or do I have to create a function to read the entire string and check for the next line tag to determine the end of this string?

Comment: Is `$swift` a multi-line `string` or an `array`? `$swift.GetType()` => `String` or `Object[]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Describe the first line more accurately, then whatever is left is necessarily the message:

```
$swift = @'
:61:2111261126D12000,00NTRF11000004217657P//03MT211124101166
JANE DOE  1232
'@
$swift |Select-String -Pattern '(?m):\d+:[^,]+,[^/]+//\d+MT\d+[\s\r\n]+.*$'
```

The regex pattern breaks down as follows:

```
(?m)        # Multi-line mode, this will make `$` match end-of-line positions as well as end-of-string
:\d+:       # 1 or more digits, surrounded by colons,            matches `:61:`
[^,]+,      # 1 or more non-commas followed by a comma,          matches `2111261126D12000,`
[^/]+//     # 1 or more non-slashes, followed by 2,              matches `00NTRF11000004217657P//`
\d+MT\d+    # 1 or more digits followed by `MT` and more digits, matches `03MT211124101166`
[\s\r\n]+   # 1 or more white-space/CR/LF characters
.*$         # everything until the end of the current line,      matches `JANE DOE  1232`
```

Since we're using `[\s\r\n]+` to describe the potential line break, it'll still work when the linebreak is replaced with other whitespace characters.